# How to fit a Deep Learning model that returns 2 outputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to create a model that returns 2 outputs: 1st is the predictions and 2nd is attention map. I am using CIFAR-10 dataset for this.

The problem is the fit method dosen't accept a model with 2 output values in the default loss function so I have to create a custom loss function. I am not able to figure out how to create the custom loss function. I have tried the following for my loss function:

```
def teacher_model_generator(input_shape, num_classes):
    inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(inputs)
    cbam_output = cbam(x)
    print(cbam_output.shape)
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(cbam_output)
    x = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax', name='out_predictions')(x)
    print(x.shape)
    return tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[x, cbam_output], name='teacher_model')

input_shape = (32, 32, 3)
num_classes = 10
teacher_model = teacher_model_generator(input_shape, num_classes)
teacher_model.compile(
    loss = {
        "out_predictions": tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
    },
    metrics = 'acc',
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
)
teacher_model.fit(xtrain, y_out_a, epochs=3)
```

My teacher model's architecture is given below:-

```
Model: "teacher_model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape                 Param #   Connected to                  
==================================================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, 32, 32, 3)]          0         []                            
                                                                                                  
 conv2d (Conv2D)             (None, 32, 32, 64)           1792      ['input_1[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 global_average_pooling2d (  (None, 64)                   0         ['conv2d[0][0]']              
 GlobalAveragePooling2D)                                                                          
                                                                                                  
 global_max_pooling2d (Glob  (None, 64)                   0         ['conv2d[0][0]']              
 alMaxPooling2D)                                                                                  
                                                                                                  
 dense (Dense)               (None, 8)                    512       ['global_average_pooling2d[0][
                                                                    0]',                          
                                                                     'global_max_pooling2d[0][0]']
                                                                                                  
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 64)                   512       ['dense[0][0]',               
                                                                     'dense[1][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 tf.__operators__.add (TFOp  (None, 64)                   0         ['dense_1[0][0]',             
 Lambda)                                                             'dense_1[1][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 activation (Activation)     (None, 64)                   0         ['tf.__operators__.add[0][0]']
                                                                                                  
 multiply (Multiply)         (None, 32, 32, 64)           0         ['conv2d[0][0]',              
                                                                     'activation[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 tf.math.reduce_mean (TFOpL  (None, 32, 64)               0         ['multiply[0][0]']            
 ambda)                                                                                           
                                                                                                  
 tf.math.reduce_mean_1 (TFO  (None, 32, 64)               0         ['multiply[0][0]']            
 pLambda)                                                                                         
                                                                                                  
 tf.expand_dims (TFOpLambda  (None, 1, 32, 64)            0         ['tf.math.reduce_mean[0][0]'] 
 )                                                                                                
                                                                                                  
 tf.expand_dims_1 (TFOpLamb  (None, 1, 32, 64)            0         ['tf.math.reduce_mean_1[0][0]'
 da)                                                                ]                             
                                                                                                  
 concatenate (Concatenate)   (None, 1, 32, 128)           0         ['tf.expand_dims[0][0]',      
                                                                     'tf.expand_dims_1[0][0]']    
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_1 (Conv2D)           (None, 1, 32, 1)             6273      ['concatenate[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 multiply_1 (Multiply)       (None, 32, 32, 64)           0         ['multiply[0][0]',            
                                                                     'conv2d_1[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
 tf.__operators__.add_1 (TF  (None, 32, 32, 64)           0         ['conv2d[0][0]',              
 OpLambda)                                                           'multiply_1[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
 global_average_pooling2d_1  (None, 64)                   0         ['tf.__operators__.add_1[0][0]
  (GlobalAveragePooling2D)                                          ']                            
                                                                                                  
 out_predictions (Dense)     (None, 10)                   650       ['global_average_pooling2d_1[0
                                                                    ][0]']                        
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 9739 (38.04 KB)
Trainable params: 9739 (38.04 KB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

I am getting the following error:

```
(None, 32, 32, 64)  --> cbam_output.shape -> output 2 of my model
(None, 10)  --> x.shape  -> output 1 of my model
Epoch 1/3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 65
     57 teacher_model = teacher_model_generator(input_shape, num_classes)
     58 teacher_model.compile(
     59     loss = {
     60         "out_predictions": tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
   (...)
     63     optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
     64 )
---> 65 teacher_model.fit(xtrain, y_out_a, epochs=3)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_file5swoecr9.py:15, in outer_factory.<locals>.inner_factory.<locals>.tf__train_function(iterator)
     13 try:
     14     do_return = True
---> 15     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16 except:
     17     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\21112\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1401, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\21112\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1384, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\21112\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1373, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\21112\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1155, in train_step
        return self.compute_metrics(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "C:\Users\21112\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1249, in compute_metrics
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "C:\Users\21112\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\engine\compile_utils.py", line 620, in update_state
        metric_obj.update_state(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=mask)
    File "C:\Users\21112\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\utils\metrics_utils.py", line 77, in decorated
        result = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\21112\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\metrics\base_metric.py", line 140, in update_state_fn
        return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\21112\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\metrics\base_metric.py", line 723, in update_state  **
        matches = ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\21112\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\metrics\accuracy_metrics.py", line 459, in sparse_categorical_accuracy
        matches = metrics_utils.sparse_categorical_matches(y_true, y_pred)
    File "C:\Users\21112\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\utils\metrics_utils.py", line 969, in sparse_categorical_matches
        matches = tf.cast(tf.equal(y_true, y_pred), backend.floatx())

    ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 10 and 32 for '{{node Equal_1}} = Equal[T=DT_FLOAT, incompatible_shape_error=true](IteratorGetNext:1, Cast_4)' with input shapes: [?,10], [?,32,32].
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, from a multi-output model, you are trying to compute loss on specific output only. Here is one way to do this: you can specify the target layer with desired loss method in the compile method. For example:

```py
loss = {
   "out_a": keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
   "out_b": keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
   "out_c": keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
}
```

Here is a toy example.

```py
(xtrain, ytrain), (xtest, _) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
xtrain = xtrain[:10000] 
ytrain = ytrain[:10000] 

y_out_a = keras.utils.to_categorical(ytrain, num_classes=10)
y_out_b = keras.utils.to_categorical((ytrain % 2 == 0).astype(int), num_classes=2)
```

```py
def teacher_model_generator(input_shape, num_classes):
    inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(inputs)
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    out_a = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='out_a')(x)
    out_b = keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax', name='out_b')(x)
    return keras.Model(
        inputs=inputs, outputs=[out_a, out_b], name='teacher_model'
    )

input_shape = (28, 28, 1)
num_classes = 10
teacher_model = teacher_model_generator(input_shape, num_classes)
teacher_model.compile(
    loss = {
        "out_a": tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
    },
    metrics = 'acc',
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
)
teacher_model.fit(xtrain, [y_out_a, y_out_b,], epochs=3)
```

```
Epoch 1/3
loss: 2.2846 - out_a_loss: 2.2846 - out_a_acc: 0.2191 - out_b_acc: 0.4930
Epoch 2/3
loss: 1.7500 - out_a_loss: 1.7500 - out_a_acc: 0.3483 - out_b_acc: 0.4930
Epoch 3/3
loss: 1.6229 - out_a_loss: 1.6229 - out_a_acc: 0.3922 - out_b_acc: 0.4930
```

This is using keras's high level API but if you want to go with a bit [mid level API](https://keras.io/examples/vision/knowledge_distillation/) you probably can get more control on this.

---

An another way to achieve this is to first train the model as usual with single input and single ouput and after finishing the training, create a feature extractor from it.

```py
def teacher_model_generator(input_shape, num_classes):
    inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu')(inputs)
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    out_a = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='out_a')(x)
    out_b = keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax', name='out_b')(x)
    return keras.Model(
        inputs=inputs, outputs=out_a, name='teacher_model'
    )
```

```py
input_shape = (28, 28, 1)
num_classes = 10
teacher_model = teacher_model_generator(input_shape, num_classes)
teacher_model.compile(
    loss = keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
    metrics = 'acc',
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
)
teacher_model.fit(xtrain, y_out_a, epochs=3)
```

After finishing the training, first inspect the layers as follows

```py
for layer in teacher_model.layers:
    print(layer.name, layer.output_shape)

input_7 [(None, 28, 28, 1)]
conv2d_6 (None, 28, 28, 64)
global_average_pooling2d_6 (None, 64)
out_a (None, 10)
```

Here the `conv2d_6` is the target layers. Now, build a feature extractor.

```py
feature_extractor = keras.Model(
    teacher_model.inputs, 
    [
        teacher_model.get_layer(name='conv2d_6').output,
        teacher_model.output
    ]
)
```

Now, you can use it as a multi-output for inference.

```py
conv2D_output, pred_output = feature_extractor(xtrain[0][None, ...])
conv2D_output.shape, pred_output.shape
(TensorShape([1, 28, 28, 64]), TensorShape([1, 10]))
```

Note, in your case I see you're using [`cbam`](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.06521) module. Specifically, you need to return the last layer name or module name in the `teacher_model.get_layer(name=[HERE]).output` method

Comment: I am trying to apply knowledge distillation using this model -(it will be the teacher model) and so I want attention maps as output from my model. But the thing is I do not have the attention maps for comparing the outputs in the way you used ```y_out_b ``` to pass as a part of y_train. I believe this is the primary reason of me getting a new error : ```ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 10 and 32 for '{{node Equal_1}} = Equal[T=DT_FLOAT, incompatible_shape_error=true](IteratorGetNext:1, Cast_4)' with input shapes: [?,10], [?,32,32].
```
how can this be resolved

Comment: If you run the above code without `y_out_b`, like `teacher_model.fit(xtrain, y_out_a, epochs=3)`, it will still work.

Comment: notice that, I set `name` in the last layer(s), i.e. `name='out_a'` and use it in the loss method. do the same.

Comment: I have tried using the method suggested by you but without any visible changes in the error. I have provided the shapes of my outputs from the model in the error section. Could you please have a look and suggest any further changes that i can make..